# How do I change rails' default database from sqlite3 to postgres, across all new projects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Apologies for the rookie question.  I would like to make postgresql my default for **all new rails apps**.  I'm aware of the command:

```
rails new my_app --database=postgresql
```

...but I have an irrational dislike for sqlite3 and for typing this extra command.  I want my rails apps to love postgres monogamously, without me telling them they shouldn't hook up with sqlite3 first.  How do I go about this?

I use rbenv (again, irrationally) to manage my ruby versions.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a `.railsrc` file in your HOME directory and put your db override there

```
# ~/.railsrc
--database=postgresql
```

You can add all other overrides that you might want to use, like `--skip-test-unit` or the like.

This file will be applied each time you run a `rails new` command.

Comment: Thank you!  Where is the origin of the sqlite3 dependency?  And would I be able to change it there?

Comment: @apiary9 sqlite3 as a default database? Hardcoded in `rails new`, I think. You don't want to change it there. That's what these overrides are for.

Comment: Ah, an answer finally!  Thank you, kind internet expert!

Comment: @apiary9: don't forget to accept helpful answers :)

Comment: Can I  specify the database version in `.railsrc`? I would like to use sqlite v1.3.6

Comment: @Sergio: no, that goes to your gemfile.

Answer (score 0):

you can change default database by changing database.yml according to given file and don't forget to add pg gem in route gemfile like this gem 'pg'

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: project_development
  pool: 5
  username: 
  password:

test: &TEST
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: project_test
  pool: 5
  username: 
  password:

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: project_production
  pool: 5
  username: 
  password:
```

if this did'nt help you see the rails cast [Migrating to PostgreSQL](http://railscasts.com/episodes/342-migrating-to-postgresql)